# Number on the left of StackExchange at top

Tags: feature-request

Often after going off for a few hours, you come back and there is a small red circle with a number inside at the top left of the page. When you click on it you can see comments and responses to your questions. However as soon as you click on it it disappears. Meanwhile you have to remember all the places you have received responses and comments to. Is it possible to have the number remain so long you do not click into each individual response?

Comment: I like this idea, since clicking through is really when you find out what each item is about.

Answer (score 5):

When you click that "StackExchange" menu it pops up three tabs. The rightmost one is "inbox" and it retains everything that has been highlighted for you in the leftmost tab, "hot questions".